# Dojo: orient TooltipDialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

There is a code:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/TooltipDialog">
  // Content
</div>
```

The problem is that content inside `TooltipDialog` can vary - moving the tooltip out of the screen:
[image]

I would like to make sure the tooltip to appear like this:
[image]

But can't find the way to make it work. There is an `orient` for Dojo `Popup`:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/TooltipDialog" data-dojo-props="orient: ['before']">
```

But this produces an error: `Uncaught TypeError: scope[method].apply is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it declaratively, but programmatic solution is as follows:

```
myTooltipDialog= new tooltipDialog({
                content: someContent,
             });

popup.open({
            popup: myTooltipDialog,
            around: buttonNode,
            orient: { "BR": "TR"},
        });
```

According to the documentation, `orient` can take an ordered hash of tuples of the form `{around-node-corner: popup-node-corner}`. `around-node-corner` is the bottom-right corner of `buttonNode` and `popup-node-corner` is the top-right corner of `myTooltipDialog` Hence, `BR` and `TR`.